# achartengine clear renderers in XYMultipleSeriesRenderer

Tags: android, dataset, time-series, achartengine, renderer

My goal is create a graph that will hide and show a series depending on user actions. I thought to do that by first clearing the graph and dataset and renderers and then reinserting the new values. Much like the `.clear()` method of Arraylists, I was wondering if there was some type of similar functionality built for the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer. I noticed that the XYMultipleSeriesDataset was lacking similar functionality, but i was able to resolve that (i think, i can't be sure yet) by doing

```
        for(int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            dataset.removeSeries(i);
        }
```

Luckily XYMultipleSeriesRenderer seems to have a getrenderercount type of method, but not a remove method that takes `ints`. All i see is a remove function that doesn't take `ints`, just actual series renderer names.

Here is more code if that helps:

```
private void excecuteGraph() {
    //      add series to the complete dataset
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    switch (graphCase ){
    case -1:
        dataset.addSeries(series0);
        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        dataset.addSeries(series3);     

        //          create the individual renderers, customize settings for each
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer1.setLineWidth(3);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        renderer2.setLineWidth(3);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.RED);      
        renderer3.setLineWidth(3);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer4 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer4.setColor(Color.WHITE);        
        renderer4.setLineWidth(3);

        //          add renderers to the complete multirenderer, customize settings for it
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer4);
        break;
    case 0:
        for(int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            dataset.removeSeries(i);
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series0);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer00 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer00.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer00.setLineWidth(3);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer00);
        break;
    case 1:
        for(int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            dataset.removeSeries(i);
            Log.d("testingGraph", dataset.toString());
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer10 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer10.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        renderer10.setLineWidth(3);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer10);
        break;
    case 2:
        for(int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            dataset.removeSeries(i);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer20 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer20.setColor(Color.RED);     
        renderer20.setLineWidth(3);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer20);
    case 3:
        for(int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
            dataset.removeSeries(i);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series3);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer30 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer30.setColor(Color.WHITE);       
        renderer30.setLineWidth(3);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer30);
    }

    mrenderer.setYTitle("Accuracy (%)");
    mrenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mrenderer.setYAxisMax(100);
    mrenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mrenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    //      Get the chart view result, add it to the linear layout
    GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset,
            mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy");

    LinearLayout graphLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_graph);
    graphLayout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));        

    if (mChartView !=null) {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question entirely, but I can give you some clues.

To remove all renderers in an `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`:

```
renderer.removeAllRenderers();
```

To remove all series in an `XYMultipleSeriesDataset`:

```
int size = dataset.getSeriesCount();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  // always remove the first element because once you remove one element,
  // the size of the list becomes size - 1 and so on
  dataset.removeSeries(0);
}
```

However, if you want to hide one single series, then just remove that one and not all of them.

Comment: perhaps i have an outdated jar or something, i've can't find the `mrenderer.removeAllRenderers();` the closest I have is `mrenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(renderer)`. which requires that i do it one at a time, which is of no use to me, because these will vary at runtime. I am doing a time series if that makes a difference.

Comment: Download 1.0.0 here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list or 1.1.0-rc1 from here: http://www.achartengine.org/download/

Comment: well i have 1.0.0 already. i'll test the rc1. do you think it would be best to extend the class and attempt my own series visibility toggler? I'm not that confident in my ability, but if it's possible i'd love to try.

Comment: 1.1.0 has the removeAllRenderers() method.

Comment: well i dunno why `repaint();` does absolutely nothing, but i've finally verified that your solution absolutely works! you should edit your answer so people will know. dan the man, my hero.

Comment: You also can't inline that call to getSeriesCount(). Would have been lovely to have a "removeAllSeries" method on the dataset.